# Google colab stuck on downloading Fashion_Mnist dataset

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

I have tried running my code from google collab for the fashion using [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ayv9LZs-Vkbw3GcaCCsgpAmPUzVrzL9i#scrollTo=XpcNCG4sqVTO) code but it is stuck on downloading the code. I also switched between the hardware accelerators but still nothing. Is there any workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download it from the [github repository](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist).
Put the downloaded files (from the readme links) in a directory in your current path called `data/fashion/`, then you can use their loader.

```
def load_mnist(path, kind='train'):
    import os
    import gzip
    import numpy as np

    """Load MNIST data from `path`"""
    labels_path = os.path.join(path,
                               '%s-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
                               % kind)
    images_path = os.path.join(path,
                               '%s-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
                               % kind)

    with gzip.open(labels_path, 'rb') as lbpath:
        labels = np.frombuffer(lbpath.read(), dtype=np.uint8,
                               offset=8)

    with gzip.open(images_path, 'rb') as imgpath:
        images = np.frombuffer(imgpath.read(), dtype=np.uint8,
                               offset=16).reshape(len(labels), 784)

    return images, labels

X_train, y_train = load_mnist('data/fashion', kind='train')
X_test, y_test = load_mnist('data/fashion', kind='t10k')
```

The other option would be to use the [torchvision FMNIST](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/datasets.html#fashion-mnist) dataset.

### Edit

You can also use:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
data = input_data.read_data_sets('data/fashion', source_url='http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/')
```

### Edit 2

Here is the code for downloading the files (it can be improved with some try-catch):

```
import os
import requests

path = 'data/fashion'

def download_fmnist(path):
    DEFAULT_SOURCE_URL = 'http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/'
    files = dict(
        TRAIN_IMAGES='train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz',
        TRAIN_LABELS='train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz',
        TEST_IMAGES='t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz',
        TEST_LABELS='t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    for f in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, files[f])
        if not os.path.exists(filepath):
            url = DEFAULT_SOURCE_URL + files[f]
            r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

            open(filepath, 'wb').write(r.content)

            print('Successfully downloaded', f)
download_fmnist(path)
```

Comment: The directory is not found. Do I need to set it up? I put it in the Colab folder. For the first solution that is

Comment: You can use the command from tensorflow that I posted in my edit (this also downloads the files in the directory), and then use the other part (the function `load_mnist`) for loading the data. Otherwise, you can directly use what you find in the variable `data` returned by tf.

Comment: This is how you can use what is inside the tf dataset directly: `x_train, y_train = (data.train._images, data.train._labels)`.

Comment: Also, it looks like your code is not stuck in downloading the dataset, but it is taking long time to execute training. No need to download it in other ways. If you still need a directory with the files, this is what you should do. Otherwise, your code looks fine to me.

Comment: tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist is not existing for some reason.You can try to run it yourself and see

Comment: My mistake, I attached the code (see edit 2) to download directly the files.

Answer (score 1):

**For Google Colab**
At the top write `!pip install mnist`.
 Use `import mnist`.
Then simply store the images and labels:

```
train_images = mnist.train_images() 
train_labels = mnist.train_labels()
test_images = mnist.test_images()
test_labels = mnist.test_labels()
```

That's it!!!

Answer (score 0):

The command `keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()` returns a tuple of numpy arrays: `(xtrain, ytrain)` and `(xtest, ytest)`.

The dataset won't be downloaded to your local storage this way. This is why the command `cd fashion-mnist/` raises an error. There was no directory created. The fashion-mnist dataset was loaded correctly into `(xtrain, ytrain)` and `(xtest, ytest)` in your code.

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Comment: Do you need the original fashion-mnist images? I couldn't not find any source where you can get them from in jpg or png format. They're only available as idx3-ubyte files. You would need to convert all 70.000 images yourself. Your code should work if you load the dataset using the `keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()` function. I 've tested your code in google colab. The execution takes a long time but it works without any errors arising.